# LinkedIn API: What determines the expiration time of an access token?

Tags: linkedin-api

When pulling information from the LinkedIn API, the access token will randomly expired, and the application will not be able to pull the information from the API. This issue randomly occurs after an extended period of time. I am trying to determine whether this could possibly be coming from LinkedIn's side. Is there any way to verify?

Comment: Are you having this problem with specific API calls? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [LinkedIn documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#hero-par_longformtext_0_longform-text-content-par_resourceparagraph), you should receive the expiration date of the access token in the same request you receive the token.

> **Access Token Response**
>
> A successful Access Token request will return a JSON object containing
>   the following fields:
>
> **access_token** — The access token for the user.  This value must be kept secure, as per your agreement to the API Terms of Use.
>
> **expires_in** — The number of seconds remaining, from the time it was requested, before the token will expire.  Currently, all access tokens are issued with a 60 day lifespan.

One thing to keep in mind is that access tokens can be manually [revoked by the user](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#hero-par_longformtext_1_longform-text-content-par_resourceparagraph):

> **Invalid Tokens**
>
> If you make an API call using an invalid token, you will receive a
>   "401 Unauthorized" response back from the server.  A token could be
>   invalid and in need of regeneration because:
>
> - It has expired.
> - The user has revoked the permission they initially granted to your application.
> - You have changed the member permissions (scope) your application is requesting.
>
> Since a predictable expiry time is not the only contributing factor to token invalidation, it is very important that you code your applications to properly handle an encounter with a 401 error by redirecting the user back to the start of the authorization workflow.

One thing that is not mentioned on this page, as @JustinKominar mentioned, is that only your most recent access token is valid. That means requesting a new access token will invalidate all of the previous ones, so make sure that your tokens are up to date!

Comment: This is all accurate info - but one thing I would add is that requesting a new access token will invalidate any previously issued ones.  Only your most recent token is valid - so check your workflow to ensure that you aren't trying to use old tokens (cache?) if a newer one has been requested by the user.

Comment: Thank you for the post. Is there a way to have LinkedIn set the expires_in field to never expire? I do not have access to the code, but our application pulls this information from the API and I'm trying to determine why the token would need to expire.

Comment: @JustinKominar can confirm, but from what I understand, it is not possible, by design. Also, keep in mind users can revoke the permissions for your application at any time, so you'd still need to be careful with your tokens in your application.

Comment: @JustinKominar "but one thing I would add is that requesting a new access token will invalidate any previously issued ones" this is not true. Currently I am observing that both an old and new access token is working in the v2 LinkedIn API.